# how to chage the height of sprite without changing the value of original of sprite in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(sprites.boundingBox.origin.x, sprites.boundingBox.origin.y, sprites.boundingBox.size.width, scale);
```

How can I assign this CGRect to a CCSprite?

```
    float scale = sprites.boundingBox.size.height * 1.2;
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(sprites.position.x,sprites.position.y + ((scale -   sprites.boundingBox.size.height) / 2));
    sprites.position = point;
    [self resizeSprite:sprites toWidth:sprites.boundingBox.size.width toHeight:scale];
    -(void)resizeSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite toWidth:(float)width toHeight:(float)height
    {
        sprite.scaleX = width / sprite.contentSize.width;
        sprite.scaleY = height / sprite.contentSize.height;
    }
```

how to animate the height scaling in up direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the scale properties. `scaleX` will change the width, `scaleY` will change the height, and `scale` will change both:

```
sprite.scaleX = 1.1f;
sprite.scaleY = 0.5f;
```

Comment: it scale one time and then i again touch its value not change i am storing its value on array and update every time on touch of sprite